# Closure of a pointclass under universal real quantification

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, determinacy

Let us assume $\mathsf{AD}^+$ and let $\Gamma$ be a pointclass such that $P(\mathbb{R})\cap L(\Gamma)=\Gamma$ and $L(\Gamma)\models\mathsf{AD}_\mathbb{R}+\mathsf{DC}$. Since the cofinality of $o(\Gamma)$ is uncountable, the Wadge-degrees of rank $o(\Gamma)$ are non-self-dual. Let us denote them by $d_0$ and $d_1$. Exactly one of the pointclasses $\{A : A\leq_w d_0\}$ and $\{A : A\leq d_1\}$ has the separation propery. Let $\Xi$ be that one.

By a result of Steel, we have that $\Xi$ is closed under $\exists^\mathbb{R}$. I wonder if it is closed under $\forall^\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Here are some partial answers : Lemma 3.6 and 3.8 of Jackson's handbook chapter tell us that if the Steel pointclass beyond $\Gamma$ is inductive-like then it must be that $o(\Gamma)$ is regular (in our starting $\mathsf{AD}^+$ model). Any model of $\mathsf{LSA}$ shows us that it's real possibility that we have an inductive-like pointclass immediately after a pointclass satisfying $\mathsf{AD_{\mathbb{R}}+DC}$.

Comment: Thanks, @SeanCody! Since I'm currently thinking about the minimal model of $\mathsf{AD}_\mathbb{R}+\mathsf{cof}(\Theta)=\Theta$, this is good enough. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.